# RSpec request spec not passing params for post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm not sure what's happening here, but I've started a new personal project and for some reason when writing request specs, the params for post requests are not coming through to the controller.
Here is my spec:

```rb
  let(:params) { {data: {type: 'user', attributes: {...}, relationships: {...} } } }
  before do
      login_as_user(user)
      post "/api/v1/users", params: params.to_json, headers: headers
  end
```

Yet when I put a pry in the controller's create action, there are no params. There's the format, the headers, the controller, and the action, but not the params from the spec.

I've never run into this problem before and am unsure of what could be causing this. I can't find anything online that addresses this issue, other than to put `as: :json` in the request spec. I did that, but it did not rectify the issue.

**UPDATE:** When I remove the headers from the request, the params come through as expected.
Here are my routes:

```rb
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, header: { name: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/vnd.api+json' }
```

Thank you for any help anyone is able to offer :D

Comment: shouldn't be `headers` instead of `header` in the route def?, also, what are you using? rails? grape?

Comment: Using rails. Either headers or header works in terms of passing the header(s). But when I use the content type header here, it won't pass the params through

Comment: Have you tried without setting that?

Comment: Yes, I had updated the question to explain that if I remove the headers, the params come through just fine. I am wanting to follow the json-api-spec and it requires that content-type header with that value be used

Comment: Have you tried a content type of 'application/json'?

Comment: I have not, yet. Was trying to keep in line with the JSON API spec

Comment: What version of RSpec do you use? Because the syntax changed and your spec (with the params nested below `params:` is the new syntax which was introduced around RSpec 3.5 was must be used in RSpec 4.

Comment: The problem with the above code is the .to_json on params. The params should just be passed as a hash in the spec